# lzw decompression in java

Tags: java, compression

i have written code for lzw algo in java. at the time of decompression it goes into infinite loop. the values above 255 are read in different manner. im giving ma code with an example.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test_decom {
  static  final int BUFFERSIZE  = 32;
static final int CHARSIZE     = 12;
static long buffer;        //32 bits of space, up to 16bit compression, only 24 bits used
static int bufferBits;     //How many bits are stored in the buffer
static int bits = 12;           //How many bits per code
static int lzwSize;       // have writen dis value at the end of compression file but this
                           //also not writing..... **plz help for this also**
static int getCode(InputStream fp)
{
 long temp;

while(bufferBits <=(BUFFERSIZE - CHARSIZE *2))//Never go over than size - or we loose data
{                                             //Also never use full 64 bits, to avoid issues
    //No point reading anymore, files done :p
    try
    {
            System.out.print("bufferBits : ");
    if(fp.available() <= 0)
          break;

       //test = fp.read();
       //buffer |= test << bufferBits;
       buffer |= fp.read() <<(bufferBits);
       bufferBits+= CHARSIZE; //Buffer now stores one more char.
           System.out.println(buffer);

    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
    System.out.println("Error in getCode" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
    temp = (buffer << (64-bits)) >>> (64-bits); //We remove the excess bits
    buffer >>>= bits; //Remove the bits from buffer
    bufferBits -= bits;
        System.out.println("temp : "+temp);
    return (int)temp; //we return the correct code
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
{
   // int prefix[] = new int[20];
    //int nextCode = 0;
   // String dict[] = new String [20];
    lzwSize =  (short)(1<<(bits)-1);
    BufferedInputStream fileIn = null;
    BufferedOutputStream fileOut = null;
try
{
    fileIn = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\project\\LzwTut\\test1_test.txt"));
    fileOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\gauri\\project\\practice\\LzwTut\\test1_Test.txt"));
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Unable to load file " + e.getMessage());
}
    ArrayList<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Dictionary dic = new Hashtable();
    String val = null;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int ab;
   while((ab=getCode(fileIn))!=lzwSize){ //i tried putting -1 but that is also not working
                                         //problem in this.... 
       //initialization
         input.add(ab);

   }
       // input.get(i) = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for(int i=0;i<input.size()-1;i++)
    //{
    try{

        if(input.get(i)<=255)
        {
            fileOut.write(input.get(i));
            //System.out.println("output : "+input.get(i));
            if(input.get(i+1)>255)
            { 
                val = (String)dic.get(input.get(i+1)-256);
                dic.put(i, input.get(i)+" "+val); 
             //   System.out.println("dic.put("+i+", "+input[i]+" "+val+")");
            }
            else
            {
                dic.put(i, input.get(i)+" "+input.get(i+1)); 
                //System.out.println("dic.put("+i+", "+input[i]+" "+input[i+1]+")");
            }

           // addDict(i,input[i],input[i+1]);//abhi tak out of bounds not solved

        }
        else
        {
           val = (String)dic.get(input.get(i)-256); 
           //System.out.print("output : ");
           for(int k=0;k<val.length();k++)
           {
           if(val.charAt(k) == ' ')
               continue;
           else
           {
               fileOut.write(val.charAt(k));
             //  System.out.print(val.charAt(k));
           }
           }
         //  System.out.println();
            if(input.get(i+1)>255)
            { 
                String val1 = (String)dic.get(input.get(i+1)-256);
                dic.put(i, val+" "+val1); 
               // System.out.println("dic.put("+i+", "+val+" "+val1+")");

            }
            else
            {
                dic.put(i, val+" "+input.get(i+1)); 
               // System.out.println("dic.put("+i+", "+val+" "+input[i+1]+")");
            }

        }

    }
catch(Exception e)
{}
    if(input.get(input.size() - 1)>255)
    {
        //System.out.print("output : ");
           for(int k=0;k<val.length();k++)
           {
               if(val.charAt(k) == ' ')
                   continue;
               else
               {
                  // System.out.print(val.charAt(k));
                   fileOut.write(val.charAt(k));
               }
           }

    }
    else{
    //System.out.println("output : "+input.get(input.size() - 1));
    fileOut.write(input.get(input.size() - 1));
    }
    try{
        fileIn.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
      //  System.out.println("output : "+input[9]);
}
}
```

example:
txt file test_test.txt contains:
stack overflow stack overflow..........
after compression:
input : 115
input : 116 output : 115
input : 97 output : 116
input : 99 output : 97
input : 107 output : 99
input : 32 output : 107
input : 111 output : 32
input : 118 output : 111
input : 101 output : 118
input : 114 output : 101
input : 102 output : 114
input : 108 output : 102
input : 111 output : 108
input : 119 output : 111
input : 32 output : 119
input : 105 output : 32
input : 115 output : 105
input : 32 output : 115
input : 98 output : 32
input : 101 utput : 98
input : 115 output : 101
input : 116 
input : 32 output : 256
input : 102 output : 32
input : 111 output : 102
input : 114 output : 111
input : 117 output : 114
input : 109 output : 117
input : 46 output : 109
input : 32 output : 46
input : 115 output : 32
input : 116
input : 97 output : 256
input : 99 
input : 107 output : 258
input : 32
input : 111
output : 260 input : 118
input : 101 output : 262
input : 114
input : 102 output : 264
input : 108
input : 111 output : 266
input : 119
input : 46 output : 268
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)//  it was supposed to write lzwSize but it is not writing

after decompression:
output : 115
output : 116
output : 97
output : 99
output : 107
output : 32
output : 111
output : 118
output : 101
output : 114
output : 102
output : 108
output : 111
output : 119
output : 32
output : 105
output : 115
output : 32
output : 98
output : 101

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while((ab=getCode(fileIn))!=lzwSize)// I think here is the problem
```

should be

```
while((ab=getCode(fileIn))<=lzwSize)
```

Because may be getCode(fileIn) will never return lzSize and it will loops forever. I dont know lzw decompression just guessing by viewing your code.

Comment: it will go out of bounds if i do for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++). m creating dictionary